# Ultra Quick Way To Concatenate Byte Values

Tags: c++, string, byte

Given 3 different bytes such as say x = 64, y = 90, z = 240 I am looking to concatenate them into say a string like 6490240. It would be lovely if this worked but it doesn't:

```
 string xx = (string)x + (string)y + (string)z;
```

I am working in C++, and would settle for a concatenation of the bytes as a 24 bit string using their 8-bit representations.

It needs to be ultra fast because I am using this method on a lot of data, and it seems frustratingly like their isn't a way to just say treat this byte as if it were a string.

Many thanks for your help

To clarify, the reason why I'm particular about using 3 bytes is because the original data pertains to RGB values which are read via pointers and are stored of course as bytes in memory.

I want a way really to treat each color independently so you can think of this as a hashing function if you like. So any fast representation that does it without collisions is desired. This is the only way I can think of to avoid any collisions at all.

Comment: itoa()? might be a n00b answer.

Comment: String manipulation is slow in general. Why not keep them as numbers until later? (You can store four bytes in a long int on most platforms)

Comment: getting a string like "6490240" is NOT the same as "24 bit string using their 8-bit representations", the latest would be "@Z≡"

Comment: You could write `char arr[256][3] = {"000", "001",...}` and then `arr[x]` to get the value. That would be ultra fast. The concatenation of 3 of these strings is also a very specific task that you could give an extra function for. Most of the usual functions are too general to be efficient in this manner.

Comment: @nobody - doesn't work you get "064090240", you need 3 lookup tables for 1,2,3 digits and some logic to combine them

Comment: @Martin Becket: Well then you would have more dynamic solutions (or `...={"0\0\0","1\0\0",...}`. The general idea remains the same. He could also have a lookup table for the 16777216 values that are possible with the 24 Bits which would be even faster(though very memory exhaustive).

Comment: Does it need to be decimal? Hexadecimal would be very easy to do fast.

Comment: Does it matter that 111, 1, 1 can't be distinguished from 1, 11, 11 in converted string form?

Comment: @vsz I know it's not the same, I was saying that although I would prefer a string concatenation, I would settle for a bit concatenation instead.

Comment: They are bytes to start with because I'm using RGB values from raw data in memory and of course these are each represented as bytes. Perhaps I shall just add that in an edit to the question in case it opens up another solution

Comment: You should just use hexadecimal representation of bytes. It's non ambiguous and conversion from and to hexadecimal are classical one-liners.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you consider instead just packing the color elements into three bytes of an integer?

`uint32_t full_color = (x << 16) | (y << 8) | z;`

Comment: That's very interesting actually. So the uint acts as the container for them whereby I'm offsetting each byte value so it sits like xyz inside the int. The only problem is the waste of 8 bits per int I suppose?

Comment: @Greenhouse Gases Even with the unused byte, it takes less space than creating a string (which can use up to nine bytes if all three colors are >= 100).

Comment: +1: 2 times faster than divisions, nearly 6 times faster than sprintf, and more than 100 times faster than stringstream. At least on my system.

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way to turn numbers into a string is to use [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
std::ostringstream os;
os << x << y << z;
std::string str = os.str();   // 6490240
```

You can even make use of manipulators to do this in hex or octal:

```
os << std::hex << x << y << z;
```

**Update**

Since you've clarified what you really want to do, I've updated my answer.  You're looking to take RGB values as three bytes, and use them as a key somehow.  This would be best done with a long int, not as a string.  You can still stringify the int quite easily, for printing to the screen.

```
unsigned long rgb = 0;
byte* b = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&rgb);
b[0] = x;
b[1] = y;
b[2] = z;
// rgb is now the bytes { 0, x, y, z }
```

Then you can use the `long int rgb` as your key, very efficiently.  Whenever you want to print it out, you can still do that:

```
std::cout << std::hex << rgb;
```

Depending on the endian-ness of your system, you may need to play around with which bytes of the long int you set.  My example overwrites bytes 0-2, but you might want to write bytes 1-3.  And you might want to write the order as z, y, x instead of x, y, z.  That kind of detail is platform dependent.  Although if you never want to print the RGB value, but simply want to consider it as a hash, then you don't need to worry about which bytes you write or in what order.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it seems like a neat way inline way of doing it. I was hesitant to use any library functions because the cumulative overheads of calling them would be a performance loss because I might need to do this several 100,000 times. Would you consider this a fast way?

Comment: This won't solve the OP's edited question because multiple colors can make the same string.

Comment: It clearly enough the simplest way and the most C++ idiomatic way, but what about the speed ? In some case ostringstream perform even worse than the old sprintf. Some measurement could be enlightning.

Comment: @Greenhouse I've updated my answer to go with your updated question.

Comment: I checked and one my system (x86 64 bits, using g++) ostringstream solution is about 200 times slower than the direct conversion I proposed (178245 cycles vs 486 cycles).

Comment: @kriss thanks for the testing, I will steer clear of ostringstream then. Are you suggesting your hexadecimal solution is better than Tim's updated solution that avoids the use of ostringstream?

Comment: @Tim I do like the look of your second solution, it is in the same style of Mark B's answer below and was an approach I hadn't considered. I can't envisage needing to ever print the values, it is purely a key so should be suitable. Thanks again

Comment: 1000000 conversions on my system: sprintf: 953 clocks, divisions: 328, ostringstream: 16156 clocks!!!

Comment: @Greenhouse Gases: if you do not need to print your key, no need to use hexadecimal, the solution Tim proposed is better.

Answer (score 2):

try `sprintf(xx,"%d%d%d",x,y,z);`

Comment: OP stated it needs to be ultra fast; sprintf is anything but fast.

Comment: A straightforward solution including divisions by ten and inserting them into a string might even be slower if not implemented very carefully.

Comment: @vsz: you bet ? Just the variadic function call to sprintf and the string parsing is certainly already much slower than all the division involved...

Comment: @kriss: I tried it out, if I'm really careful to be optimal with my divisions, use loop unrolling etc, I can manage to be 3 times faster than the sprintf. I still suggest trying sprintf (or sstream) and if the results are not satisfying, proceed with a more specific solution.

Comment: And even sprintf is more than 16 times faster than stringstream

Comment: @vsz: I agree sprintf is certainly good enough in practical cases, and there is certainly not much worse solution (from a speed point of view) than stringstream. However the solution I proposed earlier (you can check here http://www.copypastecode.com/75398) is still about 30 times faster than sprintf. How did you measured ?

Comment: I do +1 anyway sprintf is a good solution (even if it does not answer to the new question now that it has changed).

Answer (score 2):

Use a 3 character character array as your 24 bit representation, and assign each char the value of one of your input values.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can bytes be treated as chars implicitly or would the conversion to chars require extra statements? The problem I have I want to use the representation as a unique key and I'm not sure that is going to be possible with a char array. Though I suppose I could have a pointer to the start of the array and read the raw bits to get a unique representation as a 24-bit string using an array.

Answer (score 1):

Converting 3 bytes to bits and storing the result in an array can be done easily as below:

```
void bytes2bits(unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char z, char * res)
{
    res += 24; *res-- = 0;
    unsigned xyz = (x<<16)+(y<<8)+z;
    for (size_t l = 0 ; l < 24 ; l++){
        *res-- = '0'+(xyz & 1); xyz >>= 1;
    }
```

}

However, if you are looking for a way to store three bytes values in a non ambiguous and compact way, you should probably settle for hexadecimal. (each group of four bits of the binary representation match a digit between 0 to 9 or a letter between A to F). It's ultra simple and ultra simple to encode and decode and also fit a human readable output.

If you never need to printout the result, just combining the values as a single integer and use it as a key as proposed Mark is certainly the fastest and the simplest solution. Assuming your native integer is 32 bits or more on the target system, just do:

```
unsigned int key = (x<< 16)|(y<<8)|z;
```

You can as easily get back the initial values from key if needed:

```
unsigned char x = (key >> 16) & 0xFF;
unsigned char y = (key >> 8) & 0xFF;
unsigned char z = key & 0xFF;
```